# pad configuration by mmap

Tags: c, linux, posix, mmap, beagleboard

I have a beagleboard-xm rev C board. the TRM of the processor. I see some examples how to do pad configuration on the Net. here is one of the examples:

```
 int fd = open("/dev/mem", O_RDWR | O_SYNC);
if (fd < 0) {
  printf("Could not open memory\n");
  exit(1);
}

// Pad configuration
volatile ulong *pinconf;
pinconf = (ulong*) mmap(NULL, 0x10000, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0x48000000);
if (pinconf == MAP_FAILED) {
  printf("Pinconf Mapping failed\n");
  close(fd);
  exit(1);
}
// configure expansion header
pinconf[0x2174/4] = 0x001A001A; //
close(fd);
```

My question is that what is the purpose of dividing `0x2174` by 4?

I see that 0x2174 represents the pin I would like to configure(`CONTROL_PADCONF_UART2_CTS[15:0]`) on http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/spruf98x/spruf98x.pdf page778. I see that it is a 32 bit register. But I cannot get the functionality 0x2174 by 4 points the lower 16 bit of that register?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the pointer is of type "ulong" which seems to be 4 bytes on this platform. Assuming the register address for the pinconf is 0x12174 you have to divide the offset to 0x10000 by 4 to get the proper index for an array of ulongs (and therefore the correct byte address).

Answer (score 2):

Address arithmetic in C works in such a way that the address of `pinconf[n]` is the address of `pinconf` plus n *multiplied by `sizeof(ulong)`*. That's why when `sizeof(ulong)` is 4, you divide the raw offset of the target word by 4 to get the word's index in `pinconf` array.